# datatables - adding class to child rows in callback

Tags: datatables

Using latest 1.10 DataTables and came across this today and can't seem to figure it out.

I am creating a child row for every row in the table in the rowCallback to show specific data in its own row (a details/child row).

In the drawCallback I am checking if the row was selected and applying a class to it (selected array contains the DT_RowId's of the selected rows).  If you select a row and the table is drawn you need to reset this because I am using serverside.  This also works... EXCEPT for the child row.  I cannot get a class added to the child row.

I think this has something to do with the fact it is a child row being created and this is in the callback.  So far the only solution I have found is an if/else for the child row creation (if original row was in array then create child row with 'active' class applied / if not just create the child row with no class applied).

```
"rowCallback": function( row, data ) {
    //create details row **WORKS            
    dt.row($(row)).child( format(data), data.DT_RowId+'_child' ).show();            
},
"drawCallback": function() {

    $.each( selected, function ( i, id ) {
        //set active for row? **WORKS
        $('#'+id).addClass('active').find('.checkboxes').attr('checked', true);

        //set active for child row? **DOES NOT WORK
        $('.'+id+'_child').parents('tr').addClass('active');
    });
}
```

Comment: What does the resulting row HTML look like? I'm not sure what "child row" means, but it sounds invalid. Maybe you mean "sibling row"?

Comment: I am using the DataTables plugin as noted in my post and the tags.  It is certainly not invalid.

Comment: That's not helpful, which is part of the reason you're not getting much attention with this question. Please show the resulting HTML.

Comment: People who use datatables like I tagged will understand what 'child' is in terms of the plugin. On a side note - in the sense that child is used it has no bearing on applying the class to it, but rather has a connection in terms of the api and its use.

Comment: I have substantial experience with DataTables. Best of luck.

Comment: My apologies, but it appeared you did not know what 'child rows' were from your comments.  [DataTables Child Rows](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row().child())